# Onclick in a INPUTBOX - show a text near - onclick out text disappear

Tags: php, javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

I have a inputbox. What I want to make it when I click in the inputbox a text to appear NEAR the inputbox, if I click OUT inputbox, the text disappears...

I've tried this, and it works but not completely:

```
<style type="text/css">
.hidden {display:none} 
</style>
```

then

```
<input name="title" type="text" id="title" onclick="document.getElementById ('TEXT_CLASS').className = document.getElementById ('TEXT_CLASS').className == 'hidden' ? '' : 'hidden'" />
```

then

```
<span id="TEXT_CLASS" class="hidden">the text that I want to appear on click</span>
```

so this all does works, BUT, the text does not disappear when I click out, the text just toggles..

Can somebody please help me in making the text appear ONLY when "onclick", and disappear ONLY when "click out"?

Thank you

Comment: There is no jQuery code in your script.. Are you using jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say click out, I think you mean `blur`.. meaning the textbox losing focus.. Then you need to implement the onblur event.

You should implement `onfocus` and `onblur` like below.

```
<input name="title" type="text" id="title" 
   onfocus="document.getElementById('TEXT_CLASS').className = ''";
   onblur=" document.getElementById('TEXT_CLASS').className = 'hidden';"
/>
```

Probably you should consider doing this like below,

```
   <input name="title" type="text" id="title" />
   <span id="TEXT_CLASS" class="hidden">Test Class</span>

   <script>
      var titleEl = document.getElementById('title');
      var textSpanEl = document.getElementById('TEXT_CLASS');

      titleEl.onfocus = function () {
          textSpanEl .className = '';
      }

      titleEl.onblur = function () {
          textSpanEl .className = 'hidden';
      }
   </script>
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/LyKze/

Comment: Thanks, I would rather use the first method you wrote because I don't have to use Another script on site.. just trying to use less scripts. I tested in all the browsers and it works great . Thanks

Comment: @Vzlotea Read about [unobtrusive javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) to learn about 2nd approach.

Comment: To simply put.. the 1st approach couples the markup and scripts together.. while the 2nd approach has a clear separation between markup and script.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery, you can do something like

```
$('#title').click(function(){ 
     $('#TEXT_CLASS').css('display', $('#TEXT_CLASS').is(':visible') ? 'none' : 'block'); 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create a javascript function which will toggle the visibility of the span.

```
function setVisilibity(span, visible)
{
    span.style.display = visible ? "block" : "none";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set TEXT_CLASS to hidden by default and then do the following

```
$("#title").focus(functiion(){
   $("#TEXT_CLASS").show();
});
```